# SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type ti mestamp with time zone: "Invalid date"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Postgres and i don't know how to overcome this problem here : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Invalid date" what this where is the bug,? and how to overcome this bug?

Comment: put your code as well

Answer (score 0):

Change the date datatype to use `date` instead of `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` property in query must be an array, not an object.

```
{
  where: [{
    code: barcode.barcode,
    createdAt: { [Op.gt]: new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }
  }],
  defaults: {code: barcode.barcode}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove timezone from the date.

You can use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to achieve that like this

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

For example

```
const date = new Date(new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const dateString = date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');


User.findAll({
  where: {
     createdAt: { [Op.gt]: dateString }
  }
})
```